# php array order

Tags: php, arrays

How do I order an array by key, this is example:

```
array(3){
    [3] => array(),
    [2] => array(),
    [1] => array()
}
```

What I need is:

```
array(3){
    [1] => array(),
    [2] => array(),
    [3] => array()
}
```

Thanks alot.

Comment: I didn't understand the question. Can you please elaborate on your example?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: Please fix the type of the last element key, which should be 3 (I guess?)

Answer (score 2):

[ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)

> Sorts an array by key, maintaining key to data correlations. This is useful mainly for associative arrays.

Comment: Thanks alot, I feel asshamed that I didnt find that ... thanks for help anyway! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your *what I need* doesn't make sense, do you really want to kick out [3] ?
Other than that, to answer your **actual** question, to sort arrays by key, just use phps [`ksort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)

Comment: I assume the last 1 is a typo (should be 3).

Comment: `array_sort()` sorts by value, OP needs to sort by key, cf. [Sorting Arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php).

Comment: @jsengram yeah figured that a second later too :)

Comment: oeps, it was a typo, im very sorry!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is [ksort()](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php).